# StreamedResponse with Silverlight 4 polling duplex not sending updates

Tags: silverlight, wcf, polling, duplex

I'm trying to enable a streamed response using Silverlight 4 and polling duplex, but I'm getting strange behaviour when the rate at which updates are sent to the client is greater than the maxOutputDelay, which results in no updates being sent.

For example, with a maxOutputDelay of 7 seconds, and 1 update sent every 10 seconds, everything works fine. But if I have a maxOutputDelay of 1 second, and an update sent every 500 milliseconds, the updates just sit on the server side and don't get sent to the client.

It's my understanding that setting transferMode="StreamedResponse" should send the updates immediately to the client, but this doesn't seem to be working.

Here's the binding in my Web.config for the web service:

This config is based on the information from this article: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/silverlightws/archive/2010/06/25/http-duplex-improvements-silverlight-4.aspx

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are not totally focussed on using Duplex Channels (which are a pain to configure in anything but a single host scenario) it might be worth checking out alternative solutions for implementing Server Callbacks - even if that means that you have to maintain two different types of connection to your backend.

Duplex Channel Alternatives:

- [PokeIn](http://pokein.com/FAQ.aspx)
- [Kaazing WebSocket Gateway](http://kaazing.com/products/kaazing-websocket-gateway.html)

Answer (score 0):

I think this article answers the question:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/silverlightws/archive/2010/07/16/pollingduplex-multiple-mode-timeouts-demystified.aspx

The maxOutputDelay is more like an intra-message timer.  So if your message rate exceeds this delay you will never trigger a flush until the buffer fills.  It gets reset on each new message added to the queue.  So I guess we have to tune the queue size as well as this timer to achieve a maximum actual latency.

I'm not sure why the streamed response still buffers but I see it too.  Does anyone know how to tune that buffer size?

[Edited]
Ok, this article says that we cannot control the buffering int he streamed response (it is 16k in self-hosted and 32k in IIS).  So, given that, it seems like small messages coming in at a rate greater than your maxoutputdelay are a pathological case.  Maybe I have to pad them with data...

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/silverlightws/archive/2010/06/25/http-duplex-improvements-silverlight-4.aspx